# Illustrator: How to change stroke weight proportionally without scaling the objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, resize

I have a bunch of lineworks with different stroke weights. Is there a direct way to reduce/increase all stroke weights proportionally without changing the size of the objects?

Thanks,
Newton

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following script. It changes the widths of all strokes in document accordingly to the percentile value.

```
//here you can change the stroke percentual
var myA = prompt("Choose your %","80","Change width stroke");
var myPercentile = myA/100;

if(myA!=null){

    // choose all page elements
    for (var i=0;i<app.activeDocument.pageItems.length;i++){
        var myLayer = app.activeDocument.pageItems[i];

        //if element is compound make a new loop for pathItems
        if(myLayer.typename=="CompoundPathItem"){
            for(var u=0;u<myLayer.pathItems.length;u++){

                //take actual stroke size
                var myPath = myLayer.pathItems[u];
                var myMeasure = myPath.strokeWidth;

                //transform the stroke width into % choose at start
                myPath.strokeWidth = myMeasure*myPercentile;
                }

            }

        if(myLayer.typename=="PathItem"){
                var myMeasure = myLayer.strokeWidth;
                myLayer.strokeWidth = myMeasure*myPercentile;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to make it only aply for selected items

Comment: Using strokeWidth is not adequate if an object has multiple strokes.

Comment: @bisketashwin this script doesn't let you do that because it doesn't target selected items, but the entire page's items.

Answer (score 2):

Choose transform  → scale scale down (or up to increase) with scale strokes and effects enabled. Then yet again scale with opposite scale value, this time disable scale strokes and effects. Done.

This is not very good approach if your using pixel snapping as it introduces jitter (instead of a matrix concatenation). In this case i would consider scripting this.

Comment: here we can scale stroke along object scaling. But what is required is scaling just strokes without scaling object

Comment: @bisketashwin That is exactly what im describing. **Step 1** You scale object with scale strokes **enabled**. **step2** then you **disable the scale strokes option** and **scale in reverse**. End result strokes scale object stays the same. So my answer accomplishes what is required. Try it works, it is a standard affine transformation trick that is so common it even has a scientific name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this script:

```
if (documents.length) {
    sel = activeDocument.selection;
    if (sel[0]) {
        dial = new Window("dialog", "Scale Stroke Width");

        gr = dial.add("group");
        gr.add("statictext", undefined, "Scale Stroke Width by:");
        perc = gr.add("edittext");
        perc.characters = 5;
        perc.onChanging = function () {ok.enabled = !isNaN(perc.text)}
        gr.add("statictext", undefined, "%");

        ok = dial.add("button", undefined, "OK");

        if (dial.show() == 1) for (i = 0; i < sel.length; i++)
        sel[i].resize(100, 100, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, perc.text);
    }
}
```